# Event Listeners with loops and FPS

Tags: javascript

So I'm using event listeners along with a draw (with canvas) function for user control in my game and then for the screen to be rendered, however it lags and I can't figure out how to resolve the lag issue, it works fine with only mouse listeners but not keyboard. This is what my code looks like, also any tips to run with FPS over the draw function:

```
 window.addEventListener("keydown", keysPressed, false);
 window.addEventListener("keyup", keysReleased, false);

 draw = function(){
 renders();
 }
var keys = [];

function keysPressed(e) {

keys[e.keyCode] = true;

if (chat===false){

    if (keys[40] || keys[80]){

        y= y-playerspeed
        m=true
}}
function keysReleased(e) {

keys[e.keyCode] = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] so we can see the lag problem for ourselves so we can try to fix it?

Comment: Not sure if this enough, I can always add more ... I'm pretty sure this is the code where I'm having the issue, should I include all of the render code? It's a little lengthy